# React-native-app The development server returned response error code: 500 in vs code emulator

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, create-react-app

[How to solve this red emulator error?
(React native app in VScode?][1]

How to solve this red emulator error?
(React native app in VScode?

It's at start project.

I use:
Vscode + yarn android
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0RhY.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The adb port doesn't seem to be suitable. You can try the following.

```sh
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
yarn start
yarn android
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your navigations, clean gradle and try to run it. Otherwise uninstall it and then again put commands. Check Local properties and paths also.